# what is difference between sendFile and sendfile?

Tags: node.js, express

I am sending files from backend to client side and using `res.sendFile('/filename')`. but here my  concern is what is difference between `res.senFile()` and `res.sendfile()`.

Comment: sendfile is alias for sendFile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`res.sendfile()` is an older (now deprecated) API.

`res.sendFile()` is the current supported version of the API from Express v4.8 onwards.  Besides the change in name, it also documents several additional options.

Express 4.8 supported both versions and would give you a deprecated warning message if your code used `res.sendfile()`.

The doc for Express 5.0 has done away with `res.sendfile()` entirely and indicates that it only supports `res.sendFile()`, but it does appear to still be [in the code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L485) (with a deprecation warning).  Within the implementation, they still both end up calling the same underlying function.  If you are writing new code or bring older code up to date, you should be using `res.sendFile()`.

The [migration release notes for Express 5.0](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-5.html#res.sendfile), include this:

> The res.sendfile() function has been replaced by a camel-cased version res.sendFile() in Express 5.

It appears from some github developer comments that the main reason for changing was people felt that `sendfile()` was inconsistent with the camelcase naming philosophy and the name change was to fix that naming inconsistency.